# Scan single word on line (C)

Tags: c, malloc, scanf

My goal is to make a program that would scan a word from input and then save it into one large string.

I know for sure that input is always word `'\n'` word `'\n'` ...

So I'm trying to scan a single character and save it into an array and replace `'\n'` with `' '`.

My code:

```
char c;
char *line;
int len = 0;

while(!feof(stdin))
{
    len++;
    char *line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    scanf("%c", &c);
    if (c == '\n')
        line[len - 1] = ' ';
    else
        line[len - 1] = c;
}

int q;
for(q = 0; q < len - 1; q++)
    printf("%c", line[q]);
```

Ouput is error. (`RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 2s`)

For example I want for input :

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

and this for output:

```
"one two three four five"
```

Comment: Please provide more details about the precise error you’re receiving as output.

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532425/read-line-from-file-without-knowing-the-line-length

Comment: Nonononono. Just leave poor `scanf()` alone. You don't need it. You don't want to use it. You want **sane, secure, easy to use** functions, such as `getchar()` or `fgets()`. You also absolutely do not want to cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time around your while loop, you allocate a new `line`, throwing away the old value and the characters in it.  You never initialize anything except the last character, so when your loop finishes, `line` is garbage, except for the last character.  You want to just allocate a large enough buffer ONCE at the start, or use `realloc` to make the buffer larger.

You have `while(feof(stdin))` which is pretty much always wrong -- `feof` is only true AFTER failing to read a character from the input.  So you end up looping one too many times, duplicating the final character.  Check the return value of `scanf` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I made this based on your responses.

```
char c;
char *line;
int len = 0;

while (scanf("%c", &c) != EOF) {
    len++;
    line = (char *) realloc(line, sizeof (char) * len);
    if (c == '\n')
        line[len - 1] = ' ';
    else
        line[len - 1] = c;
}
```