# fscanf not reading strings into array

Tags: c

Why doesn't this main print anything? It should print the first word in the file.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  int n = atoi(argv[2]);

  char **words = new char*[n];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      fscanf(file, "%s ", words[i]);
    }
  cout << words[0] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Apart from lack of error checking, you also have undefined behaviour reading data into arbitrary memory via uninitialised pointers.

Comment: Except for the output stream, this is just C....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char **words = new char*[n];`
will allocate a buffer to hold n pointers to char, `words` is just a pointer to an array of pointers. You need allocate enough memory for `words[i]`(the pointer to ) to hold the string:

```
for (i=0; i < n; ++i ) {
    words[i] = new char[your_max_string_len];
}
```

Optionally you can use `getline` [extension of GNU](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)(if you use gcc) to do what you want:

```
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;
read = getline(&words[i], &len, stdin);
...
free(words[i]);
```

Actually, there is no magic in this function, it just does the memory allocation under the hood to save yours, and it's your responsibility to free it.

Comment: What if I don't know how many bytes the words will need? How can I look at each word, see how many bytes it needs, and then allocate that many bytes? Would I use a temp variable?

Comment: If you don't read the string, how can you know the length of the string? But you need allocate enough memory when you read the string:)

Comment: So I would read it into a temp variable, then look at the length of the string in the temp variable, then copy it into the array?

Comment: Yes, you can use a `char[your_max_string_len]` as a temp variable to read the string ,the `strcpy` to the allocated memory.

Comment: Optionally you can use `getline` [extension of GNU](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) to do what you want: `read = getline(&words[i], &len, stdin)`

Comment: @RenéG You should be using `std::string` and `getline`so you don't need to be allocating memory or worrying about buffer sizes.

Comment: @crashmstr The class uses C++, but we haven't learned any actual C++ yet, we're basically just using the C subset for now. Except for the streams.

Answer (score 2):

`words[i]` is a pointer that points to a random memory location. Make sure to make it point to allocated memory.

```
//Now words[i] points to the 1000 bytes allocated with the new keyword
words[i] = new char[1000];
//fscan will write the input to those bytes
fscanf(file, "%s ", words[i]);
```

Comment: What if I don't know how many bytes the words will need? How can I look at each word, see how many bytes it needs, and then allocate that many bytes? Would I use a temp variable?

Comment: To figure out how big the line you are reading is, you must read it until you reach the line terminator. One way of doing this is by allocating a large memory buffer, reading the data into it, and checking if the line terminator was found. If it wasn't, realloc a larger buffer, read more data into it, and check again. Here is a example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532425/read-line-from-file-without-knowing-the-line-length