# Clear fgets buffer

Tags: c, fgets

i have an issue with my code.

```
int startProg()
{
    char *method;
    method= malloc(30*sizeof(char));
    int isInteger=0;
    int num;
    do{

        printf("Seleziona il metodo \n");
        fgets(method,30,stdin);

        //it must be nothing more than 1 char inside 
        if (method[1]!= 10)
        {
            printf("Insert just one char  \n");
        }else{

            if (method[0]>='1'&&method[0]<='4'){

                 switch (method[0]){
                    case '1':
                        num=1;
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        num=2;
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        num=3;
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        num=4;        
                        break;
                }
                isInteger=1;
                //check the option choose
            }else{
                printf("Inserire un carattere valido\n");
            }
        }
    }while(isInteger==0);
    free (method);
    return num;
}

//terminal output
Seleziona il metodo 
123456789123456789123456781345646       
Inserire solo un carattere  
Seleziona il metodo 
Inserire solo un carattere  
Seleziona il metodo
```

The idea is to recive a user input, check if is a number between 1 and 4, check witch value is and then return the value.
The only issue is that when i insert a value with more than 30 digit.
I have to clean the buffer and i need my code to be portable.
Anyone as an idea?
thanks

Comment: OT: don't use magic numbers like `49` and `52` but rather `'1'` and `'4'`. You're doing it in the case labels, so why not elsewhere?

Comment: The question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532425/read-line-from-file-without-knowing-the-line-length

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read line from file without knowing the line length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532425/read-line-from-file-without-knowing-the-line-length)

Comment: what do you mean with _"larger than the fget value"_?

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question, OP wants to only use inputs 1 to 4, but keep reading if digit

Comment: Do you mean it goes wrong if the user enters say `dfkjghkjh9879857959438759kgjdflkg7`?

Comment: `(method[1]!= 10` If you mean `'\n'`, you should use `'\n'`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to clear all characters till the end of line if input was larger than the buffer reserved for `fgets()`

So, detect if that was the case

```
    if (!fgets(method, 30, stdin)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    size_t len = strlen(method);
    if (len == 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // input with '\0'????
    if (method[len - 1] != '\n') {
        // there is still data from the line in the input buffer
        clearEOL();
    }
```

and you can implement `clearEOL()` as one of these examples:

```
void clearEOL(void) {
    int ch;
    do {
        ch = getchar();
    } while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF));
}
```

Some people may prefer a for loop :-)

```
void clearEOL(void) {
    for (int ch = getchar(); (ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF); ch = getchar()) /* void */;
}
```

or even an infinite loop with `break` inside

```
void clearEOL(void) {
    for (;;) {
        int ch = getchar();
        if (ch == '\n') break;
        if (ch == EOF) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried and solved

Comment: `if (method[len - 1] != '\n')` will read outside of the buffer if `fgets()` reads a zero-length string.

Comment: Right @AndrewHenle, should have tested the result of `fgets()` in the first place. When `fgets()` does not return `NULL` the string will not be an empty string (assuming no `'\0'` bytes in input). Answer edited.

Answer (score -1):

You're allocating an unnecessary buffer for a single character input.  Also you should handle EOF (`^D` from terminal) in the event there is no more input.  This code takes advantage of the ASCII property where the digits `0` to `9` are a contiguous range, which is also true for EBCDIC (IBM's character encoding system).

(revised to handle inputs like `abc1abc` and `41`)

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Return a value between 1..4 inclusive or 0 for EOF.
 */
int
startprog()
{
    int ch, num;

    do {
        num = 0;
        (void) printf("\rchoice (1-4): ");
        while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && isdigit(ch)) {
            num = num * 10 + (ch - '0');
        }
    } while (ch != EOF && (num < 1 || 4 < num));

    return num;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void) printf("your choice %d\n", startprog());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure they want this. Consider what happens if the input is `ABC1ABC`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky OP did not specify exactly nature of the input.  The stdio input is buffered so the unnecessary input will be ignored until a valid digit is found.

Comment: Yes but if the user insert 41 for example i would like to recive an error and not a 4

Comment: Thanks, like i was saying, i was tring to use fgets to learn something new. I had alredy make a function like that with char code but mine have problem to handle 41 for ex. Thanks for your tip

Comment: @Jabberwocky If the user enters `1412314123122312412312312412312341`, this code will invoke undefined behavior because of signed integer overflow.

Comment: @AndrewHenle true, but anyway this answer doesn't answer the question. This `num = num * 10 + (ch - '0');` stuff is not in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

I rewrite my code in the definitive way
(OT) I know i don't need malloc and the rest, was just to try that i'm still learning lol.
The code now is

```
void clearEOL() {
    int ch;
    do {
        ch = getchar();
    } while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF));
}
int startprog()
{
    int num;
    char option[25];
    int isInt=0;
    do{

        printf("insert a numer (1/4)  \n");
        fgets(option,20,stdin);
        if(option[1]!='\n' || option[0]=='\n'){

             printf("Inserire solo un carattere  \n");
            clearEOL();
        }else
        {
            if ('1'<=option[0]&&option[0]<='4'){

                num=(option[0]-='0');
                isInt=1;
            }else{

                printf("Inserire 1 e 4\n");
                clearEOL();
            }

        }


    }while(isInt==0);
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Should test result of `fgets() == NULL` in case of EOF. Also its safer to say `fgets(option, sizeof (option), stdin)` than hard coding the size.

Comment: If the input is an empty line (`option[0] == '\n'` and `option[1] == '\0'`) the `clearEOL()` will clear the next line from the user!!

Comment: i've tried to chanhe the line (option[1]!='\n' || option[0]=='\n'), let me know if it's right. Just if i'm not reciving a correct value i have to press enter to continue. is this normal?

Comment: You're calling `clearEOL()` even when `fgets()` read a full line. You need to test the last character being a newline!

Comment: You'r answer does not address what was the source of the problem in the question, why that was the problem and how your answer address the problem. It will not help other who are facing the same problem.